# svg: child element alters its parent(svg container)'s size

Tags: javascript, css, svg, d3.js

Look at the picture below:

[image]

The svg container becomes larger whenever the chart is zoomed in (d3js). How come the child element(svg:g)'s change in size affects the size of its parent container(svg)? How do I prevent this from happening?

```
var svgContainer = d3.select(".graph-container").append("svg")
  .attr("id", "firstGraph")
  .attr("width", w + margin[2] + margin[3]) // labels are placed in the margins
  .attr("height", h + margin[0] + margin[1])
  //.attr("viewBox", "0 0 "+(w+margin[2]+margin[3])+" "+containerHeight)
  //.attr("preserveAspectRation", "xMidYMid")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin[2] + "," + margin[0] + ")")
  //.append("svg:g")
  //.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin[2] + "," + margin[0] + ")"); //origin at (marginLeft, marginTop)

var graph = svgContainer.append("svg:g")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h)
  .call(zoom);

var rect = graph.append("svg:rect")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h)
  .attr("class", "plot");

//draw price data line
graph.append("path")
  .attr("d", line1(priceData))
  .attr("class", "price");

//draw difficulty data line
graph.append("path")
  .attr("d", line2(difficultyData))
  .attr("class", "difficulty");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [clipPath](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367):

```
svgContainer.append("defs").append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("rect")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);
```

...

```
graph.append("path")
  .attr("d", line1(priceData))
  .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
  .attr("class", "price");
```

[MDN on clipPaths](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath)

Comment: You're very awesome. Do you care to answer my follow-up question with zooming?

Comment: In https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Zoom-Behavior, you can specify x and y values for zoom(). What if you have two y-axes?

Comment: Might be a better way of doing this: I would just manually set the second y domain manually in .on('zoom, ... )

Comment: Hey Adam, take a look when you have time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20321458/d3js-zooming-when-there-are-two-y-axes