# d3js: zooming when there are two y axes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

reference: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Zoom-Behavior

```
//make zoom
var zoomFirst = d3.behavior.zoom()
  .x(x)
  .y(y1)
  .scaleExtent([0, 3])
  .size([w, h])
  //.center([w/2+200, h/2-200])
  .on("zoom", zoomedFirst);

function zoomedFirst() {
  svgContainer.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
  svgContainer.selectAll(".y.axis.axisLeft").call(yAxisLeft);
  //set y2's scale manually
  svgContainer.select(".price")
    .attr("d", line1(priceData))
    .attr("class", "price");
  svgContainer.select(".difficulty")
    .attr("d", line2(difficultyData))
    .attr("class", "difficulty");
}
```

`d3.behavior.zoom()` supports autoscaling of x and y axes. However, I have to scale two y axes at the same time. When zoom() is triggered, I can get the current `scale` and `translate` info from `d3.event.scale` and `d3.event.translate`, but I cant figure out how to make appropriate scale for the second y axis(`y2`) with them.

I am also looking at https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales.

Since `y1`'s range is automatically adjusted by `zoom`, if there is a way to get `y1`'s current range, I can get its min and max and set `y2`'s range based on them. However, the document doesn't specify a way to get `range` given a `scale` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `y1.range()` (without any arguments) will return you the `[min, max]` of the scale.

From the [docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#wiki-linear_range):

> If values is not specified, returns the scale's current output range.

Most accessor functions in D3 work like this, they return you (get) the value if you call them without any arguments and set the value if you call them with arguments and return the `this` object for easy chaining:

```js
d3Object.propertyName = function (_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return propertyName;
    propertyName = _;
    return this;
}
```

However, the `zoom` behaviour alters the `domain` and not the `range` of the scales.

From the [docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Zoom-Behavior#wiki-x):

> Specifies an x-scale whose domain should be automatically adjusted when zooming.

Hence, you do do not need to get/set the `range`, but instead the `domain` of the scales `y1` and `y2`: `y2.domain(y1.domain())`.

Comment: Thanks! This could be a start. I need to get the current range of y1, which is adjusted by zoom. Is there a way to do something like `zoom.y.range()`?

Comment: @MaximusS Yes, `zoom.y().range()` But I have updated the answer further.

Comment: One more problem. y1's domain and y2's domain are different. For example, y1's initial domain is [0,100], while y2's initial domain is [0,100000]. In this case, should I get the initial ratio between these two domains and apply it? For example, ratio would be 100000/100 in this case, and if y1.domain() returns [50,51], y2's domain should be [50000,510000]?

Comment: @MaximusS In this case, I suspect scaling the data might be a _better_ thing to do such that the scales are the same. However, your solution will also work.

Comment: Thanks. One more question.. Right now `zoom()` is called on the entire svg container, and it makes scrolling a little unpleasant. Is it possible to restrict the zooming area just inside the `rect` instead of the entire `svg`?

Comment: @MaximusS Yes. `zoom` behavior can be added to any element, but is usually used with `g` and `svg` since they contain other elements and set up their own coordinate system. Translating/zooming them will translate/zoom the elements inside. You should put all your elements in a `g` and apply `zoom` behavior to it.

Answer (score 2):

Since the zoom function already manages all the ratios, a more abbreviated answer would be:

```
var zoomFirst = d3.behavior.zoom()
  .x(x)
  .y(y1)
  .scaleExtent([0, 3])
  .size([w, h])
  .on("zoom", function() {
    zoomSecond.scale(zoom.scale());
    zoomSecond.translate(zoom.translate());

    // Update visual. Both y domains will now be updated

  });

// Create copy for y2 scale
var zoomSecond = d3.behavior.zoom()
  .x(x)
  .y(y2)                // <-- second scale
  .scaleExtent([0, 3])  // <-- extent
```

This assumes you have called only zoomFirst to your visual.